# ctree. Put classification node number in variable

Tags: r, machine-learning

I have a classification tree made by

```
library(party)
model.cart <- ctree(qtcf ~ ., data=training)
```

In my case I would like to create a new variable in my training set (training) and testing set (testing) indicating the terminal node number for the particular observation.

Evidently, it could be made manually like this:

```
training$ctreegroup[((training$sex == 'female') & (training$rs12143842.y>0) 
                    & (training$rs735951>0))] <- 'node14'
testing$ctreegroup[((testing$sex == 'female') & (testing$rs12143842.y>0) & 
                      (testing$rs735951>0))] <- 'node14'
```

But is there a smart way to doing this automatically without manually programming all the decisions?

Comment: I think the `where` function in `library(party)` will help. `where(model.cart)`

Comment: Thanks. I could not see the function in the party documentation but  training$node_placement <- where(model.cart) worked.

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by shuckle

```
training$node_placement <- where(model.cart)
```

worked for the training set. Unforunately it does not work on the testing set, as

```
testing$node_placement <- where(model.cart)
```

produced the error

```
Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, ctreegroup, value = c(22L, 22L, 23L,  : 
  replacement has 4440 rows, data has 1478
```

So the function where does not reexamine the data

Comment: try `predict(model.cart,newdata = testing,type = "node")`

Comment: That had soluted my problem. Tx